# Как подключить .js библиотеку с другого порта хоста

Tags: javascript, html

Библиотека Socket.io лежит на `mydomain.com:8080`

`mydomain.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Как подключить ее со страницы на `mydomain.com:80` явно не указывая ip или имя домена?

`<script src=":8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` - естественно не работает и запрашивает `mydomain.com/:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: Думается, никак, а зачем такие извращения?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать jQuery.getScript, подставляя туда нужные параметры. Текущий домен будет в document.location